# Stripe customer integration

Tags: stripe-payments

have some question about Stripe integration.
Recently, I've had a problem with the paymentmethod limit.
One user had already reached the limit of 400 records.

Temporary, there is the solution to delete payment methods for expired records. This approach has to be more automatic.
So, also there are bunch of repeating paymentmethods. By meaning of repeating is now we have same records repeat themselves more then 2 times.

Probably the logic is not right here, to attach payment methods in this way.
For now this is the solution i figured out. Is it correcnt in this way to make it or not?

Also, I've been pondering about making some new customers if the customer has already reached the pm limit. Here is the question, is there any customer limit for the Stripe account?

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit for customers in a Stripe account (though it's best to confirm with Stripe Support), but removing expired PaymentMethod sounds like a better approach than having multiple customers representing the same individual.